# Getting this error while training - ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, training-data, rasa-nlu

I am trying to train a model for chatbot and created the following files.

Model configuration file **config_spacy.json**

```
{
    "pipeline": "spacy_sklearn",
    "path":"./models/nlu",
    "data":"./data/data.json"
}`
```

Training file **nlu_model.py**

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config

def train_nlu(data, config, model_dir):
    training_data = load_data(data)
    trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUModelConfig(config))
    trainer.train(training_data)
    model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name = 'weathernlu')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_nlu('./data/data.json','config_spacy.json','./models/nlu')
```

On running the file, I am getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "nlu_model.py", line 13, in 
>           train_nlu('./data/data.json','config_spacy.json','./models/nlu')
>         File "nlu_model.py", line 8, in train_nlu
>           trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUModelConfig(config))
>         File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\config.py", line 103, in **init**
>           self.override(configuration_values)
>         File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\config.py", line 180, in override
>           self.**dict**.update(config)
>       ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I searched a lot but I am unable to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the training data that you are using. Make sure there are a minimum of two intents with at least two examples in each so that the classifier can run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think

`trainer = Trainer(RasaNLUModelConfig(configs))`

should be

`trainer = Trainer(config.load(configs))`, because `load()` contains `read_yaml_file(filename)` which you wont get by directly calling `RasaNLUModelConfig()`, correct me if I'm wrong, I'm also learning, :)

your final code should look like

```
def train_nlu(data, configs, model_dir):
     training_data = load_data(data)
     trainer = Trainer(config.load(configs))
     trainer.train(training_data)
     model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name = 'weathernlu')
```